# Unexpected SettingWithCopyWarning

Tags: python, pandas

I've been avoiding most SettingWithCopy warnings by using `.loc[: (foo, bar)]` construction.

But I don't know how to properly construct one case:

```
for sec in security_list:
     stochs.loc[:, (sec,'entry_signal')][stochs[sec, 'raw_signal'].shift(1) == stochs[sec, 'raw_signal']] = 0
```

What I'm trying to do:  in the `stochs` dataframe, add a new column, `entry_signal`.  `entry_signal` is 1, 0, or -1.  It's 0 if the `raw_signal` is unchanged from the previous `raw_signal`, otherwise it's the value of the `raw_signal` (1 or -1).

I guess pandas doesn't like the second indexing fragment, `[stochs[sec, 'raw_signal'].shift(1) == stochs[sec, 'raw_signal']]` because that spawns a copy.

Can anyone advise how to re-write this statement properly?

Thanks

Comment: try `stochs.loc[stochs[sec, 'raw_signal'].shift(1) == stochs[sec, 'raw_signal'], (sec,'entry_signal')] = 0`

Comment: @EdChum Yeah, that worked.  Didn't realize such indexing would work.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change to:

```
stochs.loc[stochs[sec, 'raw_signal'].shift(1) == stochs[sec, 'raw_signal'], (sec,'entry_signal')] = 0
```

what you did is called [chained indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy) as you were double subscripting so you should put the condition inside the brackets to `loc`

Comment: Yeah, I guess the `stochs[sec, 'raw_signal'].shift(1) == stochs[sec, 'raw_signal']` returns a list of row indices that I pass into the `.loc[]` first parameter.